# jquery, split execution of $(document).on content for speed sake

Tags: jquery

I  have this listener on my web app, that listens to a range slider :

```
    $(document).on("slidestop","#levelrange",function () {            
        var newValue = parseInt($('#levelrange').val());
        $("div.ui-slider div.ui-slider-track .ui-btn-text").text(newValue);  //displays the range value on the slider
        setLevelText(newValue);
        resetListsModelsOn(prodata, funfeatureOn,0);
        //add images to selects
        addProImagesInSelect();
        addBrandImagesInSelect();
    });
```

however, I would like this line to be executed really quick (because it updates the value displayed to the user) :

```
$("div.ui-slider div.ui-slider-track .ui-btn-text").text(newValue);
```

but these 2 lines are very long to execute and delay the previous action :

```
setLevelText(newValue);
resetListsModelsOn(prodata, funfeatureOn,0);
```

Can you help me figure out a way to execute the first action very quickly ?

Thanks

Comment: use `id` - no faster than that , and if you want it real quick - dont use jQuery.

Comment: I think you should optimize the two functions if you want them to execute faster. :)

Comment: thanks but that's not my question...I want to separate the execution of the first action and the other actions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't normally recommend this, but it is a solution. You can use a `timeout`:

```
$(document).on("slidestop","#levelrange",function () {            
    var newValue = parseInt($('#levelrange').val());
    $("div.ui-slider div.ui-slider-track .ui-btn-text").text(newValue);  //displays the range value on the slider
    setTimeout(function() {
        setLevelText(newValue);
        resetListsModelsOn(prodata, funfeatureOn,0);
        //add images to selects
        addProImagesInSelect();
        addBrandImagesInSelect();
    }, 9);
});
```

It has other drawbacks, as it is asynchronous.

Comment: thanks, although some won't like this solution, I think it is just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use common class for them:

```
$(".cmnClass").text(newValue);
```

And if want to perform even more faster use javascript instead of jquery:

```
document.getElementClassName('cmnClass').innerHTML(newValue);
```

Comment: I can't do this, because the element is generated by JQuery Mobile, I can't control its class or id.